# mongodb how to return list of value only from find query

Tags: mongodb

i have a collection placements, each record has fields: placement_id, program_id, category, ...
i need to find all placements what has program_id = 3 or 5 and only return a list of placement_id.

when i tried this command:

```
db.placements.find({program_id:{$in: [3, 5]}}, {placement_id:1, _id:0})
```

i got records:

```
{ "placement_id" : 196 }
{ "placement_id" : 197 }
{ "placement_id" : 198 }
...
```

is there any way to return just:

```
[196, 197, 198...]
```

Comment: {196, 197, 198...} is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The cursor from `find()` is going to yield JSON documents, no matter what.
But you can extract the values you want.  Something like this perhaps :

```
get_placement_id = function(doc) { return doc.placement_id; }

db.placements.find({program_id:{$in: [3, 5]}}, {placement_id:1, _id:0}).map( get_placement_id )
```

==>

```
[ 196, 197, 198, ... ]
```

Comment: do you if there any java function to implement the map() here?